# Downloading large files from google drive on Windows 10?

Tags: google-drive-api, windows-10, google-oauth

I'm trying to download zip files from google drive comprising about 20gb, it has 10-15 files and some files are as large as 4 gb, and i was downloading files 1 by 1, but the files exceeding 1.5gb are not being downloaded completely. A lot of content is missing from them, for eg, i tried downloading the 3.5gb file and after download its just 1.2g with fewer files inside.

I tried this,

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ID_OF_FILE?alt=media -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer ACCESS_TOKENS"} -OutFile file1.zip
```

but i'm getting error that only

"only files with binary content can e downloaded. Use export with Google Docs files"

Any solution  to this problem?

Comment: Yes, don't try to download a Google Sheets or Google Docs or Google Slides or Google ____ file as its native mimetype. You have to export them to a serializable mimetype, such as .xslx/.csv, or .docx/.ods, .ppt, and so on. The error is quite explicitly clear if you take the time to read it and look at the file that caused the error...

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Google Docs cannot be downloaded by alt=media of files.get. Unfortunately, the raw Google Docs cannot be downloaded, you can export them as several mimeType. This has already said by tehhowch. So when you want to download Google Docs, please use files.export, and conver to other mimeTypes as tehhowch say.

As a sample, when you download a Spreadsheet using Invoke-RestMethod, the command is as follows. In this sample, the file is downloaded by converted to xlsx file.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer ACCESS_TOKENS"} -OutFile sample.xlsx
```

#### Note :

When you use this, please use the mimeType corresponding to the Google Docs. If you want to know the mimeType that can be exported when you download Google Docs files, you can retrieve the data using drive.about.get as follows.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=exportFormats -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer ACCESS_TOKENS"} -OutFile sample.txt
```

#### Referencs :

- [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [drive.about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to think of about the workaround.